# How to read single file in my data using Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm new in Flask, I want to take single file that have been uploaded in my upload path. Then i want to read and send it to my html after hr tag. How can i do that?

This is My Code:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, url_for, abort, \
    send_from_directory
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS'] = ['.txt', '.doc']
app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'] = 'uploads'


@app.route('/')
def home():
    files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])
    return render_template('home.html', content=files)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    uploaded_file = request.files['file']
    filename = secure_filename(uploaded_file.filename)
    if filename != '':
        file_ext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
        if file_ext not in app.config['UPLOAD_EXTENSIONS']:
            abort(400)
        uploaded_file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'], filename))
    return redirect(url_for('home'))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And This one is my HTML Page:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>File Upload</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file"></p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
    </form>
    <hr>
    {{ content }}
  </body>
</html>
```

It saves the data, but I can't access the data since I use this code`files = os.listdir(app.config['UPLOAD_PATH'])`

Comment: Are you trying to display the names of all the files in that directory, or the content of a specific file?

Comment: In particular, are you trying to display all files, or only the once a user just uploaded?

Comment: actually only one, i want to read the text inside, not only displaying the title

Comment: I mean the content inside the file that just uploaded

Answer (score 0):

1. You need a variable route that will accept the a filename like `@app.route('/<filename:filename>')`.
2. You then need to get the file with that name from your upload directory like `file_path = os.path.join('UPLOAD_PATH', filename)`.
3. Then you need to read the contents of that file and pass it into your view.

```
with open(file_path) as file:
    content = file.read()
```

4. Then you can access it in your HTML file and display it.

```
<p>{{ content }}</p>
```

Here is a complete example of the route I described:

```
@app.route('/<filename:filename>')
def display_file(filename):
    file_path = os.path.join('UPLOAD_PATH', filename)
    with open(file_path) as file:
        content = file.read()
    return render_template('display_file.html', content=content)
```